# DRY up js.erb files (include another js.erb file)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Most of my js.erb files contains something like this at the bottom:

```
$("#flash_message").html("<%= escape_javascript(content_tag(:p, flash[:note], :class => "note")) %>");
$("#flash_message").fadeOut(2000);
$("#loading").remove();
```

I would like to move these lines into a seperate file and then call that file from each of my js.erb files. Is something like that possible?

Best regards.
Asbørn Morell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you may create an `app/views/shared/_flash_messages.js.rjs` partial, which you can then render from anywhere (e.g. from other `rjs` partials.)

My approach in these kinds of applications has been as follows:

- for non-AJAX responses that may have a flash:

  - in the layout (e.g. `layouts/application.erb`), add e.g.:
    `render :partial => 'shared/flash_messages.html.erb'`
- for AJAX responses that may also need to display a flash message, I added the following `rjs` code:

  - in each `rjs` response (e.g. `controller/action.js.rjs`), add e.g.:
    `render :partial => 'shared/flash_messages.js.rjs'`

Where the two partials do the necessary to render the flash, then call `flash.discard(:error)` or `flash.discard(:notice)` as appropriate.

Sample `app/views/shared/flash_messages.html.erb` file:

```
<% if flash[:error] %>
<div id="flash_message" class="error"><%= h(flash[:error]) %></div>
<% flash.discard(:error) %>
<% elsif flash[:notice] %>
<div id="flash_message" class="notice"><%= h(flash[:notice]) %></div>
<% flash.discard(:notice) %>
<% else %>
<div id="flash_message" style="display: none;" />
<% end %>
```

Sample `app/views/shared/flash_messages.html.rjs` file:

```
if !flash[:error].blank?
  page['flash_message'].
    replace_html(flash[:error]).
    removeClassName('notice').
    addClassName('error').
    show()
else
  page['flash_message'].
    replace_html(flash[:notice]).
    removeClassName('error').
    addClassName('notice').
    show()
end
```

Comment: Thankyou. This was exactly the kind of example I was hoping for. My js.erb files is much cleaner now ;)

Answer (score 0):

`<%= render :partial => 'common' %>`, perhaps?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000633