# Best way to extract .js.erb from the page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I have shared javascript infused with `erb` shared across two pages, (in my case looking up a route) how and where is the best place to extract that `.js.erb` file? Options as I see them:

1. Extrapolate the status quo to 2 copies of the same code on two pages (ugh...)
2. Extract the `.js.erb` into a file and keep it in the view folder.
3. Extract the `.js.erb` into a file somewhere in public/javascripts.

What would you do in this case?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602934/dry-up-js-erb-files-include-another-js-erb-file

Comment: @ghoppe - thanks, I was doing some searching around that myself a few minutes ago :) +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Extracted into an `html.erb` partial in the views folder, from where it is accessible to both `new` and `edit` actions for that controller. This solves the redundancy problem while keeping it in a logical place.